# Custom string attribute breaks Android Studio's ConstraintLayout preview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, custom-attribute

I created a custom view extending the AutoCompleteTextView. Also I have custom attributes related to that. When I set the custom string attribute value in the layout, the constraint layout *design screen preview* stops properly working. When I remove the custom string attribute, the constraint layout works properly. This only takes place at design time, there is no problem at run time. I reinstalled and updated Android Studio but it didn't help me. My codes and screenshots are below:

[broken view when setting custom attribute named model_field](https://ibb.co/eNP4Cq)

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DATV">
        <attr name="model_field" format="string"/>
        <attr name="search_type" format="enum">
            <enum name="never" value="0"/>
            <enum name="always" value="1"/>
            <enum name="depended" value="2"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/e_mail_adresi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView16" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView4"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView7"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/telefon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView17" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView8" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/tc_kimlik_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView18" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/arac_bilgileri"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/marka"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" android:labelFor="@+id/carBrandDATV"/>
        <tr.com.universe.raportiz.lib.views.CarBrandDATV
                app:model_field="@string/CarBrand_name"
                app:search_type="always"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/carBrandDATV"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"
        />
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/model"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/carBrandDATV"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        />
        <tr.com.universe.raportiz.lib.views.CarModelDATV
                app:model_field="@string/CarModel_name"
                app:search_type="depended"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/carModelDATV"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/plaka"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/carModelDATV" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <tr.com.universe.raportiz.lib.views.CarDATV
                app:model_field="@string/Car_plate_no"
                app:search_type="always"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/plateNoDATV"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/sasi_numaras"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plateNoDATV" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <tr.com.universe.raportiz.lib.views.CarDATV
                app:model_field="@string/Car_chassis_no"
                app:search_type="always"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/motor_numarasi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView8" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <tr.com.universe.raportiz.lib.views.CarDATV
                app:model_field="@string/Car_engine_no"
                app:search_type="always"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/arac_sahibi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/ad_soyad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView10" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/tc_kimlik_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView11" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView3" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/telefon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView12" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/e_mail_adresi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView13" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView4"/>
        <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/alici_bilgileri"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView14" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/ad_soyad"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView15" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView6" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/tc_kimlik_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView19" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView6"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView9" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/telefon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView20" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView9"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView10"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/e_mail_adresi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView21" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView10"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView11" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:background="@drawable/edittext_selector"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I remove the `model_field` attributes, the preview works properly like below

[the view when I remove the custom attributes named "model_field"](https://ibb.co/ermvJV)

Comment: check Car_engine_no string resource

Comment: @navylover it already exists like `<string name="Car_engine_no">Car.engine_no</string>`. The custom views with attribute `model_field` slides up to the top of the layout. The constraints not working with custom attribute.